# Debugger issues with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug, watchface

I'm learning how to develop watch faces under Android Studio. I have annoying issues with the debugger, which makes it a pain to use.

When I want to run my face in debug mode, I keep having this message:

```
...
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.wearmodule.test | com.example.wearmodule
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.wearmodule.test | com.example.wearmodule
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.wearmodule.test | com.example.wearmodule
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.wearmodule.test | com.example.wearmodule
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

The only option I seem to have is to first execute my face in run mode, and then attach a debugger to the process. However, very often I can't since the 'OK' button is grayed, as the screenshot shows:

[image]

When, luckily, I can attach a debugger, it keeps disconnecting after a few seconds/minutes with this message:

```
Disconnecting run session: a new debug session will be established.
```

But no other session is established. This makes the process of debugging extremely uncomfortable.

Did I miss something in the configuration of Android Studio?

Edit: It might be worth noting that even when I simply try to run the application, I often get the message `Client not ready yet...` continuously. In these cases, I have to restart the emulator. This happens every other attempt to run the app, which makes me lose a lot of time.

Comment: Just restart your emulator or Disconnect your device and reconnect again.

Comment: How is your `adb`? Does it shows your device using `adb devices`? I usually `adb kill-server` then restart the IDE.

Comment: @MayurPatel I keep doing that everytime I get disconnected. The problem keeps happening, so this is not a viable solution.

Comment: @shkschneider Yes my emulator is showed with `adb devices`.

Comment: Maybe a firewall of yours is blocking outgoing or incoming packages from your local device? Since attaching a debugger is done via socket-connections this might be an issue?

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama As far as I know, I don't use any firewall. I'm under ArchLinux if it's relevant.

Comment: Could this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/53962831/ help you?