# How do I fix "Could not connect to remote process" while trying to debug the application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I am making a android studio project and I try to debug my application.

Running the application works fine, but when I try to debug it I get this error:

`Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.`

What can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to restart the ADB.

kill adb.exe process.

[how to restart ADB manually from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826101/how-to-restart-adb-manually-from-android-studio)

Comment: Killing the adb.exe by hand works for me every time. Manual restart from the studio does not work, when I get this error.

Comment: This works for me, but only when it's in use and I have to force kill it.  "taskkill /IM adb.exe /F" Which happens when it's in actual use trying to connect.  If I stop the debugging session and then kill it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes this happens when two Android-capable IDEs are opened, e.g. Android Studio and IDEA. Shutdown one of the two (or disable Android plugin in IDEA) helps.

Comment: Definitely one of the use cases. When this is happening, no other solutions work.

Answer (score 17):

In My case, 
For some reason I disabled Instant run and it has changed the Launch value from "Default Activity" to "Nothing" in "Run/Debug configurations". So always it says "Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session" and I was not able to debug. I enabled Instant  and changed the Launch value from "Nothing" to "Default Activity"   in "Run/Debug configurations" and it worked. Hope this will help some one.

(to get Run/Debug configurations, click "app" drop down and click Edit Configurations)

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks a million @nuwancy

Comment: killing the adb.exe was usleese for me , but this work like charm ;) +

Comment: after loosing some  hours i find this solution. thanks man.

Comment: The answer hit my problem :-) Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Check if you have selected the right Build Variant, usually "**release**" comes with `debuggable false`

Example:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            ....
        }
    }
```

is not recommendable change **release** to `debuggable true`, just change the right variant

```
   debug {
        debuggable true
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Verify on AndroidManifest that your LAUNCHER activity has:

```
android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 5):

I try invalidate cache / restart and it's work

Answer (score 4):

In command line :

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server
```

This command will restart ADB

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Kuzneц's answer.

When Intellij and Android Studio are both open, apparently the Android plugin in Intellij needs to be disabled.  This wasn't always the case but it resolve the issue for me.

- Mac OSX 12.2.1
- IntelliJ 2021.3.1
- Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Comment: Thank you, this is the only way that resolves my issue.
In my case is Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 3, cannot connect to Debugger using AVD Android API 29,

Answer (score 2):

By default Android Studio builds the `debug` version of the application. However, during the publishing phase you may have switched to the `release` one as the tutorial suggests.

ADB won't be able to attach to the application unless you revert to the `debug` configuration **or** you allow to the debug the `release` one.

If nothing of this works, you may resort in restarting ADB as explianed in [How to restart ADB manually from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826345)

**Revert to debug configuration**

1. Choose *Build->Select Build Variant*
2. Pick up `debug` in the second column
3. Deploy the application again

**Allow the release version to be debugged**

1. Select your application node in the tree
2. Right click and choose *Open Module Settings* (or hit F4)
3. Select *Build Variants* on the left
4. Choose `release` on the right
5. Set `debuggable` to `true`
6. Apply and deploy the application

Keep in mind that your life won't be easy as your application may be optimized and therefore not debugger friendly (e.g. you might not be able to step in certain methods, or view some local variables).

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote so that I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Restarted the ABD server. First the device had to be connected. Look for the "Assistant" tab in android studio (on the right side it usually is), and press next until you see the option to reset the ABD server.

Answer (score 1):

I did

--->adb kill-server && adb start-server

--->invalidate cache / restart

but not work yet

```
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test

Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test
    
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test
    
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

image1:--> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZF5D.png

image2:--> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrE4a.png

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading android studio to Bumblebee, this solution worked for me as well a teammate, Thanks @Mosen_AB

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when the phone was connected both via wi-fi (using "adb tcpip 5555" and "adb connect 192.168.0.100:5555" commands) and via a usb cable. Disconnecting the USB cable resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions posted here did not help me. I eventually discovered that creating a new simulator instance (tools->AVD Manager->Create virtual device) solved my problem. I was unable to get the previous simulator working again.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the recommendations above, but the problem was solved only after I used the Generate Signed Bundle and selected the desired flavor

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a wrong launch flag set in the Run/Debug Configurations. I found out about this by taking the adb command that is executed to launch the app, which can be found in the "Run" tab. The command looks like this:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.your.package...." -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

By executing the command manually in the terminal, i got an error message which pointed me to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All solution didn't fix my issue, If you face it same me try that solution
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711539/how-to-fix-error-could-not-connect-to-remote-process-aborting-debug-session)

Answer (score 0):

- My case

  - use `Android Studio` create a simple android app but **no activity**

    - current settings: `Android Studio`->`Run`->`Edit Configuration`->`General`->`Launch Options`->`Launch`: **Nothing**

      - for later used as Xposed plugin, which is no need UI=activity
- Error

  - first `Timed out waiting for process to appear on`
  - final error: `Processes are not found Aborting session`
- Reason

  - for Android app, `activity` ~= `process`

    - no activity mean can not debug
- Solution

  - for me

    - done nothing

      - for no activity android app: can NOT debug

        - activity == UI page ~= proecess, so no activity means no process, cause can not debug
  - for others (normal android with activity)

    - change `Launch` to **Default Activity**

      - [image]