# Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session

Tags: android, c, android-studio

I'm making a android studio project and I try to debug my application.

Running the application works fine, but when I try to debug it I get this error:

> ```
> "Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session."
> ```

Comment: This appears to be a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962831/how-do-i-fix-could-not-connect-to-remote-process-while-trying-to-debug-the-app). (except for the language, which is really not relevant anyway.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix "Could not connect to remote process" while trying to debug the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962831/how-do-i-fix-could-not-connect-to-remote-process-while-trying-to-debug-the-app)

Comment: I applied the methods at the address you specified, but it did not work.
I wanted to know if anyone has up-to-date information by asking here.

Answer (score 3):

try **Invalidate cache and restart** Android Studio. Works for me.